# Reset MinimumDate in iOS UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have 2 **UIDatePickers**, one set in **UIDatePickerModeDate** and the other in **UIDatePickerModeTime**.

If the first one has its date set to **today**, then the second one must have a restriction such that the user cannot select a time that is before **now**. To do this I use the **setMinimumDate** function. However, if the user sets a date in the future, I need to reset the **minimumDate** property, meaning that there should be no **minimumDate** set on the picker.

I am able to achieve this by calling

```
 [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:nil];
```

But this gives me an exception in the Xcode console output as below.

```
-[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil
Future exception.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply be ignored.
```

How can I remove the **minimumDate** property of my **timePicker** after it has been set, without this exception being raised?
Thank you.

EDIT:
The reason I tried setting it to **nil** was because Apple's documentation says that the default value of the **minimumDate** property is **nil** ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615980-minimumdate)).

Also, I did try to set the minimum date to the future date selected by the user, after making the time component zero. This causes the time to be selected as 12 AM in the picker which is acceptable. Now if the user selects today's date again, nothing happens when I set the **minimumDate** property, i.e. I cannot toggle the **minimumDate** using this. The code is as follows:

```
(void)setMinimumDateForTimePicker {
 if([[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:self.datePicker.date]) {
      NSLog(@"Min date for today");
      [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:[self roundUpToNearestFifteenMinutes:[NSDate date]]];
 } else {
     // date is in the future so zero out time
     NSLog(@"Min date for the future");
     NSDateComponents* selectedDateWithZeroTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
 [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:selectedDateWithZeroTime]];
 }
 [self updateStartTimeField:nil];

}
```

Comment: Well, the error message tells you the answer. I don't know what you think "reset" means, but what you set the date to cannot be `nil`. What does "reset" mean to you? If you want it to have no minimum date, i.e. one is permitted to pick a date as far back in the past as possible, then use `Date.distantPast`. If you mean the start of today, then use the start of today. But you cannot say `nil`, that's as plain as it can be.

Comment: Did you try setting custom date along with time? eg. Today date 14:00.
meaning can't select time before 14:00

Comment: @matt I edited my question to add more details and clarify its meaning.

Comment: @AnisMansuri I tried what you suggested but I cannot seem to toggle the minimumDate setting for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked finally for what I was trying to do.

```
- (void)setMinimumDateForTimePicker {
    if([[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:self.datePicker.date]) {
        [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:[self roundUpToNearestFifteenMinutes:[NSDate date]]];
    } else {
        [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]]];
    }
    [self updateStartTimeField:nil];
}
```